# Sending List into Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm still trying to get my head wrapped around .net MVC, and maybe I'm just not searching the right key words to find my answer.

In short, I have a partial view that has a list that I want to include in the main view.

Index.cshtml:

```
@Html.Action("Checklist")
```

Checklist.cshtml:

```
@model List<Area>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h4 class="text-center">Outcomes</h4>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item)</p>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public PartialViewResult Checklist()
    {
        var outcomeAreas = db.OutcomeArea.Select(oa => oa.Area).Distinct();
        return PartialView("Checklist", outcomeAreas.ToList());
    }
```

Edit: I get a weird rendering now in the html when testing the website.  if you look at the page source code, I see:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] List<Area>
```

Comment: Could you edit into your question the definition of the class `Namespace.toModel`please? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view is expecting a model of type `List<Namespace.toModel>` but the type of the `outcomeAreas` variable passed to it appears to be either `IEnumerable<OutcomeArea>` or `IQueryable<OutcomeArea>`

Try changing `Checklist.cshtml` to have this at the top:

```
@Model List<OutcomeArea>
```

And then change your controller action to return:

```
return PartialView("Checklist", outcomeAreas.ToList());
```

**Edit:** Just noticed that you're doing `.Select(oa => oa.Area)`, so you'll actually want to use whatever type the 'Area' property is. `@Model List<Area>` or `@Model List<string>` if it's a string, etc..

Comment: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Area) should be Html.DisplayFor(item => item.Area)?

Comment: @upsidedowncreature That's actually allowed, since it uses the `item` variable declared in the loop.

Comment: I was querying the use of `modelItem` as that isn't what's declared in the loop. Admittedly @Brian Mains expressed it a lot more clearly!

Comment: @upsidedowncreature It's the way Visual Studio generates razor views for you; they can't redefine `item` in the lambda since it's already using a variable called `item` in the for loop. Since `Html.DisplayFor( => )` needs a lambda, they had to put something in there.

Comment: Every day's a school day :)

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  So I have a different error now, saying Model is NULL.

Comment: @yondaimehokage Can you update your question with your current code?

Comment: Just did.  :) Ben

Comment: @yondaimehokage Ah, your `Index.cshtml` needs to use `Html.Action("Checklist")` to call the controller action which will return the partial view. Using `Html.Partial("Checklist")` is shorthand for including the `Checklist.cshtml` view directly, but skipping the action. That would be used if you already had something to pass to the view, as `Html.Partial("Checklist", model.AreaListIAlreadyHave)`

Comment: @yondaimehokage Just noticed that you're doing `.Select(oa => oa.Area)`, so you'll actually want to use whatever type the `Area` property is. `@Model List<Area>` or `@Model List<string>` if it's a string, etc..

Comment: Thank you so much, Ben!  It's working now.  I will my code.

Comment: I lied.  I now get this issue popping up when rendered in the html: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] List<Area>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139566/discussion-between-ben-jenkinson-and-yondaimehokage).

Answer (score 0):

I think this specific error is related to the fact that the lamdba doesn't use the same alias:

```
<p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Area)</p>
```

to

```
<p>@Html.DisplayFor(item => item.Area)</p>
```

The lambda alias and usage has to match.   I think this is what the CS1001 error usually refers to, but @Ben's answer is a change also needed; either have the model expect IEnumerable, or as he said, call `ToList()` in the action method to ensure it's a list type.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right; but I think the CS1001 error is being thrown because of the model type mismatch, it probably can't use the Model keyword then. But if we use `item` in the lambda _as well_ as the variable from the `for` loop, we'll have a different error :)